# Quadrature rules for products of 2D regions

Tags: integration, quadrature, polynomials

I am interested in computing integrals of the form $\iint_{P\times P} Q(x_1,x_2,y_2,y_2) dxdy$ where $P$ is a polygon and $Q$ is a polynomial. The coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$ are in the plane of $P$. Of course $(y_1,y_2)$ represent again coordinates in the plane of $P$, possibly different from previous ones.

The above integral can be computed explicitly in terms of integrals of the form $I(p,q)=\int_P x_1^px_2^q$, but formulas quickly become really ugly (lots of binomial coefficients). There is an obvious strategy:

- evaluate $I(p,q)$ numerically (exact quadrature rule) or analytically
- find the exact decomposition of $\iint_{P\times P} Q(x_1,x_2,y_2,y_2) dxdy$ into sum of products of terms of the form $I(p,q)$

However, I'm interested to know if other strategies, more efficient and possibly more precise were developed.

> Do you know any other efficient methods for computing $\iint_{P\times P} Q(x_1,x_2,y_2,y_2) dxdy$ where $P$ is a polygon and $Q$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Given that your integrand is a polynomial, I think you'll be hard pressed to beat numerical quadrature. Maybe there's a slight bit of trickiness to decompose your polygon into simple shapes (tris/quads) that have well known rules.

Comment: @rchilton1980: I will try numerical quadrature, splitting the polygon into triangles. For low degree the computations should be good enough.